# Reference in EGA

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I was reading the proof of a statement in EGA 0.10.3.1.3 (hope I got that right, it's in the third volume actually), which I am in need of. There are several references to other parts of EGA, precisely (0.6.2.3), (0.6.6.2), (0.7.3.5) and (0.6.6.1). When I looked them up in EGA I, where I thought them to be, the statements belonging to these numbers had nothing to do with the proof. In fact it seems that (0.6.2.3) does not exist at all. I would be glad if someone could help me out of my confusion and/or point out a mistake I might have made. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For chapter 0 references, the notation (0${}_{\text{III}}$, 10.3.1.3) indicates via subscript the part to which that piece of chapter 0 is attached.

The references in the proof you're reading are to (0${}_\text{I}$, 6.2.3), etc., so you need to look in the piece of chapter 0 attached to part I. Looking up that particular example (on page 56 of part I), I see a proof that a direct limit of flat modules is flat, which indeed proves the claim in (0${}_{\text{III}}$, 10.3.1.3) referencing it.

**Edit:** Note that you need to be using the [*first* edition of EGA I](http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1960__4__5_0/). The second edition is kind of an orphan, so not terribly useful.

Comment: Thanks. I was indeed using a new version of EGA 1. Then this appears to have caused the seemingly misplaced numbering.